# How to increase Canvas size in Android?

Tags: android, canvas

Is there anyway to increase Canvas size more then my screen size in Android? Like if my screen size is 320 x 480 I want to increase my canvas size 3 times bigger then that.

Comment: but there is no scaleTo(..) method... there is canvas.scale(sx, sy);
            canvas.scale(sx, sy, px, py);

Comment: can you explain why you need that? because than we might have some ideas :)

Comment: ok i have a binary file which contains image tiles. basically this is a map and i have drawn the map on canvas by reading that file now issue is when i move that map it is really slow movement because on every movement maximum 20 tiles get loads and draw on canvas... so thats why i want to increase my canvas size and also i want to move my canvas with my finger so i do not need to redraw all the tiles again and again. this is an idea i got for smooth movement. now if you can give me any idea it will be really appreciative. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bitmap of desired size and then draw needed part of it to canvas using drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) method of canvas.