# How to add text above a marker on android Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I made an android application and i want add text above (or below) a marker. I found this link [How to add text above a marker on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286258/how-to-add-text-above-a-marker-on-google-maps) but it's for the old api of google maps. So i wonder if we can do the same thing with the new api ?

I have ever tried to do this with this code :

```
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pin_favoris).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setTextSize(25);
canvas.drawText("Favoris", 0, bm.getHeight(), paint); // paint defines the text color, stroke width, size
BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
Bitmap drawBmp = draw.getBitmap();
// gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fakeMarker, 15));
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(fakeMarker)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawBmp))
        );
```

but the text can only be displayed in the Bitmap (not above/below) !

Comment: Hi did you manage to do this in the end? I need to do this too

Answer (score 13):

if you just need to add text above a marker, do something like this:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(
           "fsdfsdf sdfsdf")).showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: I'm adding multiple markers, this works but shows the info window for only one marker. Any procedure to show all the infowindow?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue "It shows only for one marker"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

```
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(fakeMarker)
    .title("Favoris")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_favoris))
);
```

Comment: Yes but the title function add an Info window. I don't want a window, i just want a TextView above my marker

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make your Bitmap / Canvas bigger, then you can draw your text above the marker.

This should help: [How to increase Canvas size in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724996/how-to-increase-canvas-size-in-android)

Comment: I've tested the method scale like this :
`canvas.scale(1, 1);`
but nothing change. If i put bigger values, my text doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Try to create a new bitmap, which is bigger, and then draw the two "components" onto it.